# Permissions issue in Munin

Tags: permissions, fedora, user-management, munin

I have a Fedora machine on which I have successfully installed and configured Munin.

The issue that I now face is of permissions. So basically, I have a directory where I have pointed all my html graphs. That directory lies in the directory of another user, let us say `johndoe`. So, I went to my `/home` folder as root and executed the following command:

```
chmod -R ug+rwx /johndoe
```

But still, the user `munin` doesn't seem to have permissions to get inside the /johndoe directory (a simple `cd` didn't work!). I have a constraint that I cannot do a 777 on the folder as the information inside might be sensitive. So, what should I do so as to give the munin user access to the directory? I worked pretty easily on Ubuntu. Is there a different way of doing things on Fedora?

Comment: Did you also add the munin user to the group that group-owns `/johndoe`?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `usermod -a -G johndoegroup munin`; don't forget to restart munin's processes after that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a typo there and did

```
chmod -R ug+rwx /home/johndoe
```

or

```
chmod -R ug+rwx johndoe
```

inside /home, right?

The difference between Ubuntu and Fedora are probably the user/group assignments.

Did you try to give everyone access to the home of this user and the the munin user (munin?) access to this specific subdirectory?

```
chmod 0751 /home/johndoe
chown johndoe:munin /home/johndoe/htmlgraphs
chmod 0775 /home/johndoe/htmlgraphs
```

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. And yes I did a `chmod ug+rwx johndoe` and also `chown johndoe:munin /home/johndoe/htmlgraphs`, but I'm still getting a `Permission Denied`.